# Como criar MASK com JS puro no React

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, react

Estou transformando um site HTML, CSS e jQuery em React porém vi que o uso do jQuery é defasado no React já que é possível criar alguns componentes de forma mais rápida e simples, minha dúvida é como transformar um mask feito em jQuery para Javascript puro, ou melhor como fazer esse procedimento de maneira mais eficaz no React ?

Meu código Mask é este:

```
/* Mask Contato */
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.date').mask('11/11/1111');
  $('.time').mask('00:00:00');
  $('.date_time').mask('00/00/0000 00:00:00');
  $('.cep').mask('00000-000');
  $('.phone').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
  $('.phone_with_ddd').mask('(00) 0 0000-0000');
  $('.phone_us').mask('(000) 000-0000');
  $('.mixed').mask('AAA 000-S0S');
  $('.cpf').mask('000.000.000-00', {reverse: true});
  $('.valor').mask('000.000.000.000.000,00', {reverse: true});
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dê uma olhada nessa biblioteca: [text-mask](https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask), com ela você consegue fazer masking de várias formas.